# How can I import the optaplanner examples project to Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, optaplanner

I use Windows 10, jdk1.8.0_111, Netbeans 8.0.1, apache-maven-3.6.2.  I am trying to open the optaplanner examples to Netbeans.

To do so, when I open the project in Netbeans I go to the file

> c:\Program Files\optaplanner\examples\sources.

(In my system an I see a POM file in the sources folder, but NetBeans sees a 'source' (POM?) file). I see that the examples project is now in the project área of Netbeans. But I am not able to run.

The problems happen because Netbeans points to an error in one method of the file `ConferenceSchedulingConstraintProvider.java`. The method is

```
private Constraint talkPrerequisiteTalks(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(Talk.class)
            .join(Talk.class,
                    containing(Talk::getPrerequisiteTalkSet, Function.identity()),
                    lessThan(talk1 -> talk1.getTimeslot().getStartDateTime(),
                            talk2 -> talk2.getTimeslot().getEndDateTime()))
            .penalizeConfigurable(TALK_PREREQUISITE_TALKS,
                    Talk::combinedDurationInMinutes);
}
```

Referring to the line starting with '.join(Talk.class'..., the message states:

> The type of join(Class,BiJoiner,BiJoiner) is erroneous
>     where B,A are type-variables:
>       B extends Object declared in method join(Class,BiJoiner,BiJoiner)
>       A extends Object declared in interface UniConstraintStream
>   incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) B#1,A#2,B#2,Property_#1,T,A#3,B#3,Property_#2
>       (argument mismatch; BiJoiner cannot be converted to BiJoiner)
>     where B#1,A#1,A#2,B#2,Property_#1,T,A#3,B#3,Property_#2 are type-variables:
>       B#1 extends Object declared in method join(Class,BiJoiner,BiJoiner)
>       A#1 extends Object declared in interface UniConstraintStream
>       A#2 extends Object declared in method containing(Function>,Function

I  would appreciate having some help.
Amaral

Comment: Looks like a bug in NetBeans. It compiles fine in JDK 8 and IntelliJ. Workaround: remove all ConstraintProvider classes.

Comment: I created this issue to investigate this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1706

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in NetBeans but in a very old, no longer supported version.

**Temporary workaround:** download latest OptaPlanner distribution (7.29.0.Final or 7.30.0.Final) where the mentioned piece of code is commented out (Constraint Streams is still an incubating feature).

**RECOMMENDED solution:** Download and install latest NetBeans (11.2) from https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html. The problem is also fixed in NetBeans 8.2 but that's also no longer supported. I advise to use the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a serious bug in NetBeans.

It's valid Java 8 syntax, that works fine in OpenJdK, Maven, Gradle, IntelliJ, VSCode, Eclipse, ...